# Journal of Statistical Software class breaks preview in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex, debugging, preview

I'm using `AUCTeX 11.86-11` on Debian stable.

The `jss.sty` style file contained in the [JSS style file zip archive](http://www.jstatsoft.org/downloads/JSSstyle.zip) breaks AUCTeX's preview for me even with a simple file. NOTE: the `jsslogo.jpg` file is also required.
For example,the following file

```
\documentclass[article]{jss} 
\begin{document} 
$x$ 
\end{document}
```

gives the error

> LaTeX found no preview images

The more detailed error is:

```
ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \MYLATEXline.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.386   \gdef\FV@BeginScanning#1^^M
                                   {%
```

Can any AUCTeX user

1. confirm this
2. tell me what the problem is?

I'll also try the AUCTeX list and update here if a solution is found.

Comment: I can confirm that I don't get as far in the process using `jss` as I do with `article`, but I can't get `preview-latex` to work in the first place… :-P For `article`, Emacs will at least display the stand-in image for overlay.

Comment: I believe it may have something to do with `jss` automatically including the image in the document, and AUCTeX cannot find a position to place the overlay.  That's my best guess.

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks for the feedback. Indeed it is possible that including the image has something to do with it. That is quite an unusual thing for a journal to do.

Comment: @SeanAllred I removed the image from the style file, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I didn't have a problem compiling it

Comment: @SeanAllred can you provide an answer? I'll delete mine if requested by Faheem Mitha, since the question begs the question, I think your answer would be the correct answer, for it confirms what the op wanted...

Comment: @doed I can't do that in good faith—I won't be able to get it working on my end. (I've all but given up on `preview-latex`.)  You should flesh out yours, particularly including exactly what you did to solve the problem. (`latex` will check many places for files; where did you put the `jss` assets?)

Comment: @SeanAllred ha! nowhere dissimilar than what you probably did. First `texmfhome`, then the error about the missing logo, Then I was eagerly looking for errors, so I copied the logo to `texmfmain` and there it was in preview

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the site allows me to do this. I had no problems with the above class, except that its logo must be in LaTeX path. If requested, I can delete the answer.

#### Update

If I run Preview LaTeX with pdfTeX or the default engine in AUCTeX, then the following errors occur:

```
  l.386   \gdef\FV@BeginScanning#1^^M
                                     {%
  ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \MYLATEXline.
  <to be read again> 
                     1
  l.389 \endgroup
                 
  ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \MYLATEXline.
  <to be read again> 
                     1
  l.395 ...be discarded. Hit <return> to continue.}}
                                                    
  ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \MYLATEXline.
  <to be read again> 
                     1
  l.402 \gdef\FancyVerbGetLine#1^^M
```

Which at least confirmed some of the errors as stated by Faheem Mitha. But as soon as `TeX-engine-set` is set to `XeTeX`, then Preview LaTeX compiles perfectly without further errors as shown below in the first unedited output of the document.

Furthermore, if the required file *.jpg is removed from LaTeX path, regardless of the engine, then:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: File `jsslogo' not found.
 ...
 LaTeX exited abnormally with code 1
```

and the document would not compile.

#### Left unedited

Unfortunately, the results I got, fail to answer the question. First, because it can't confirm the errors of Preview LaTeX in AUCTeX as experienced by Faheem Mitha, nor it can't recreate them, nor much less give an explanation of the problems, for I had none. Furthermore, I have to come to the conclusion that my answer is too localized for the question, since other known members like Sean Allred confirmed the problem of Preview LaTeX in AUCTeX with the `jss.cls` and was even able to reproduce some of them.

Faheem Mitha requested not to delete the answer, and to provide details of the output that was obtained.

The files were unzipped, and consequently included in TDS accordingly, and later followed by `mktexlsr`. The only error I encountered while compiling it, was about the missing logo file, which as the op stated, is a requirement of the class file. This minor nuisance was later resolved by including the `jpg` logo.

Here is a detailed description of the packages that were loaded by the class in the compiled output of the document.

```
  Running `Preview-LaTeX' on `_region_' with ``xelatex  "\nonstopmode\nofiles\PassOptionsToPackage{active,tightpage,auctex}{preview}\AtBeginDocument{\ifx\ifPreview\undefined\RequirePackage[displaymath,floats,graphics,textmath,sections,footnotes]{preview}[2004/11/05]\fi}" "\input" _region_.tex''
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
   restricted \write18 enabled.
  entering extended mode
  LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
  Babel <3.9g> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
  
  No auxiliary output files.
  
  (./_region_.tex  !name(jssauctexsample.tex)
  (~/texmf/tex/latex/jss/jss.cls
  Document Class: jss 2013/04/06 2.2 jss class by Achim Zeileis
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
  Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def)))
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ae/ae.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ae/t1aer.fd)))
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
  Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
  <2008/02/07> (tvz)) (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)))
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
  
  ! LaTeX Error: \makeindex undefined.
  
  See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
  Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
   ...                                              
                                                    
  l.795 \renewcommand\makeindex
                               {\NAT@makeindex
  ) (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
  
  Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.
  
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
  
  Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperindex' has already been used,
  (hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 444.
  
  ) (./_region_.aux) (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
  (~/texmf-local/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty
  (~/texmf-local/tex/latex/preview/prtightpage.def)
  (~/texmf-local/tex/latex/preview/prauctex.def
  No auxiliary output files.
  
  
  (~/texmf-local/tex/latex/preview/prauctex.cfg))
  (~/texmf-local/tex/latex/preview/prfootnotes.def)
  Preview: Fontsize 10.95pt
  Preview: PDFoutput 1
  ) (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
  
  Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.
  
  
  Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
  (hyperref)                removing `\\' on input line 5.
  
  (~/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
  ! Preview: Snippet 1 started.
  <-><->
        
  l.5            \begin{document}
                                 
  <use  "jsslogo.jpg" >
  Preview: Tightpage -32891 -32891 32891 32891
  ! Preview: Snippet 1 ended.(4288418+0x5885636).
  <-><->
        
  l.5            \begin{document}
                                 
  [1] (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pzc.fd)
   !name(jssauctexsample.tex) !offset(-3) 
  ! Preview: Snippet 2 started.
  <-><->
        
  l.9            $
                  x$
  ! Preview: Snippet 2 ended.(308974+0x410139).
  <-><->
        
  l.9            $x$
                    
  [2] (~/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ae/t1aett.fd) )
  (see the transcript file for additional information)
  Output written on _region_.pdf (2 pages).
  Transcript written on _region_.log.
  
  Preview-LaTeX exited as expected with code 1 at Sun Dec 29 23:07:36
  Running `Preview-PDF2DSC' with ``pdf2dsc _region_.pdf _region_.prv/tmp6152      Lva/preview.dsc''
  
  Preview-PDF2DSC finished at Sun Dec 29 23:07:36
  Running `Preview-Ghostscript' with ``gs -dOutputFile\=\(_region_.prv/tmp6152Lva/pr1-\%d.png\) -q -dDELAYSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=png16m -r138.521x138.593''
  
  Preview-Ghostscript finished at Sun Dec 29 23:07:36
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer seems fine, except that it could use more details with regard to "its logo must be in LaTeX path". Did you add the path location of the logo to the LaTeX path yourself, and if so, what exactly did you do? I don't even know what the LaTeX path is. I assume what you have shown above is a screenshot of your emacs buffer? You did not specify.

Comment: @FaheemMitha yes. It is a screenshot. The dark background does not contrast well with the face of the font, hence the change to a lighter theme. I wanted to get serious errors, other than the missing logo, but my emacs didn't. I'll try to edit the question, but what else to say, when you get something in the lines that say: `Preview-LaTeX exited as expected with code 1 at Sun Dec 29 23:07:36`

Comment: Ok, but what about "its logo must be in LaTeX path"? OK, I see that you wrote in a comment above "so I copied the logo to texmfmain and there it was in preview". I'm not sure what you mean by "copied the logo to texmfmain".Can you elaborate? In any case, this should be in your answer, not in a question.

Comment: Addendum: if by LaTeX path you mean where the system looks for LaTeX files, then it certainly looks in the same directory as the top level file, in my case `test.tex` This is where I've put the logo file. In any case, regular compilation goes without a problem.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'll edit my answer. In the meantime, when you run `kpsexpand '$TEXMFMAIN"` in the terminal, what does it return? something in the lines of `/texmf-dist/tex/latex`, right?

Comment: `kpsexpand '$TEXMFMAIN'` gives me
`/usr/share/texlive/texmf`.

Comment: I know there may be disagreement as to where to put `jss.cls`, `jss.dtx` and `jsslogo.jpg`, but to be safe `mkdir jss` and put them in there.

Comment: "but to be safe mkdir jss and put them in there". Why? I've always put these at the same level as my main file, and they are found without problems. One more thing I forgot to mention is that I have another copy of `jss.cls` on my system. E.g. `/usr/share/R/share/texmf/tex/latex/jss.cls`. I wonder if that could be causing problems, though I assume LaTeX looks in the current directory first.

Comment: And does `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` returns? Let's go to chat to sort this out, or try to at least.

Comment: Did you experience this problem before with the aforementioned `jss.cls`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12207/discussion-between-doed-and-faheem-mitha)